# Is it possible to display custom sys_file_metadata only for specific file types or for files inside a specific subfolder in TYPO3?

Tags: filesystems, metadata, typo3-7.6.x

I am working on a file list extension and want to know if I can set additional meta data only for specific file types like pdf or for all files within a specific subfolder.

So far I have extended the sys_file_metadata with the following setup:

**ext_tables.sql**

```
CREATE TABLE sys_file_metadata (
    tags int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    type int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0'
);

CREATE TABLE sys_file_metadata_tags_mm (
    uid_local int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    uid_foreign int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    sorting int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,
    sorting_foreign int(11) unsigned DEFAULT '0' NOT NULL,

    KEY uid_local (uid_local),
    KEY uid_foreign (uid_foreign)
);
```

**sys_file_metadata.php**

```
<?php
defined('TYPO3_MODE') || die();

$l1 = 'LLL:EXT:file_portal/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:';

$additionalColumns = [
    'tags' => [
        'exclude' => 1,
        'label' => $l1 . 'tx_fileportal_domain_model_file.tags',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'select',
            'renderType' => 'selectMultipleSideBySide',
            'foreign_table' => 'tx_fileportal_domain_model_tag',
            'MM' => 'tx_fileportal_fileallocation_tag_mm',
            'size' => 10,
            'autoSizeMax' => 30,
            'maxitems' => 9999,
            'multiple' => 0,
            'wizards' => [
                '_PADDING' => 1,
                '_VERTICAL' => 1,
                'edit' => [
                    'module' => [
                        'name' => 'wizard_edit',
                    ],
                    'type' => 'popup',
                    'title' => 'Edit',
                    'icon' => 'edit2.gif',
                    'popup_onlyOpenIfSelected' => 1,
                    'JSopenParams' => 'height=350,width=580,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1',
                ],
                'add' => [
                    'module' => [
                        'name' => 'wizard_add',
                    ],
                    'type' => 'script',
                    'title' => 'Create new',
                    'icon' => 'add.gif',
                    'params' => [
                        'table' => 'tx_fileportal_domain_model_tag',
                        'pid' => '###CURRENT_PID###',
                        'setValue' => 'prepend'
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'type' => [
        'exclude' => 1,
        'label' => $l1 . 'tx_fileportal_domain_model_file.type',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'select',
            'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
            'foreign_table' => 'tx_fileportal_domain_model_filetype',
            'minitems' => 0,
            'maxitems' => 1,
            'items' => [
                ['Bitte wählen', 0]
            ],
            'appearance' => [
                'collapseAll' => 0,
                'levelLinksPosition' => 'top',
                'showSynchronizationLink' => 1,
                'showPossibleLocalizationRecords' => 1,
                'showAllLocalizationLink' => 1
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns('sys_file_metadata', $additionalColumns);
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes('sys_file_metadata', 'tags, type');

return $GLOBALS['TCA']['sys_file_metadata'];
```

This is working great and I can add some custom tags and a custom more specific type for my files, but this options are available for all my files now. Is there a way to display this options only for specific file types or for files within a specific subfolder, maybe with display conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with displayCond in the TCA. Check the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Columns/Index.html#displaycond).

If you want to depend on some field, that field should be added to the requestUpdate option in the ctrl section in the TCA of the table. Check the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/Reference/Ctrl/Index.html#requestupdate)

Now if the value of that field is changed, you're asked to reload the form as the fields may change.

Comment: Ok, I have added some display conditions now and this looks much better now, but how can I add a "requestUpdate" list for the file meta data tca?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to add a "requestUpdate" to the TCA of sys_file_metadata, because the ExtensionManagementUtility don't contain something like this or am I wrong? Display conditions works so far for me and here is my example with conditions for the sake of completeness:

```
<?php
defined('TYPO3_MODE') || die();

$l1 = 'LLL:EXT:file_portal/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:';

$additionalColumns = [
    'downloadable' => [
        'exclude' => 1,
        'label' => $l1. 'tx_fileportal_domain_model_file.downloadable',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'select',
            'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
            'items' => [
                ['No', 0],
                ['Yes', 1],
            ],
            'minitems' => 0,
            'maxitems' => 1
        ]
    ],
    'tags' => [
        'displayCond' => 'FIELD:downloadable:>:0',
        'exclude' => 1,
        'label' => $l1 . 'tx_fileportal_domain_model_file.tags',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'select',
            'renderType' => 'selectMultipleSideBySide',
            'foreign_table' => 'tx_fileportal_domain_model_tag',
            'MM' => 'sys_file_metadata_tag_mm',
            'size' => 10,
            'autoSizeMax' => 30,
            'maxitems' => 9999,
            'multiple' => 0,
            'wizards' => [
                '_PADDING' => 1,
                '_VERTICAL' => 1,
                'edit' => [
                    'module' => [
                        'name' => 'wizard_edit',
                    ],
                    'type' => 'popup',
                    'title' => 'Edit',
                    'icon' => 'edit2.gif',
                    'popup_onlyOpenIfSelected' => 1,
                    'JSopenParams' => 'height=350,width=580,status=0,menubar=0,scrollbars=1',
                ],
                'add' => [
                    'module' => [
                        'name' => 'wizard_add',
                    ],
                    'type' => 'script',
                    'title' => 'Create new',
                    'icon' => 'add.gif',
                    'params' => [
                        'table' => 'tx_fileportal_domain_model_tag',
                        'pid' => '###CURRENT_PID###',
                        'setValue' => 'prepend'
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
    'type' => [
        'displayCond' => 'FIELD:downloadable:>:0',
        'exclude' => 1,
        'label' => $l1 . 'tx_fileportal_domain_model_file.type',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'select',
            'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
            'foreign_table' => 'tx_fileportal_domain_model_filetype',
            'minitems' => 0,
            'maxitems' => 1,
            'items' => [
                ['Choose', 0]
            ],
            'appearance' => [
                'collapseAll' => 0,
                'levelLinksPosition' => 'top',
                'showSynchronizationLink' => 1,
                'showPossibleLocalizationRecords' => 1,
                'showAllLocalizationLink' => 1
            ]
        ]
    ],
];

\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addTCAcolumns('sys_file_metadata', $additionalColumns);
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addToAllTCAtypes(
    'sys_file_metadata', 'downloadable, tags, type'
);

return $GLOBALS['TCA']['sys_file_metadata'];
```